# all elements of ($Z$/p$Z$)* are cubes

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

Let $p$ be a prime

An element $a \in$ ($Z$/p$Z$)* is called a cube if there exists $b \in$ ($Z$/p$Z$)* such that $a = b^3$

How to show that all elements of ($Z$/p$Z$)* are cubes ?

And if $p \equiv 1$ ($mod$ $3$) Then How many elements of ($Z$/p$Z$)* are cubes ?

Answer (score 2):

$(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^\ast$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/(p-1)$.  So, your question is asking when is the multiplication by 3 map $\mathbb{Z}/(p-1)\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/(p-1)$ surjective.  It is surjective when the kernel is trivial, i.e., when $3x$ is never zero, for $x\not=0$.  This happens exactly when $3\nmid p-1$ which means that $3\mid p+1$ (since $3$ can't divide $p$) which means that $p+1=3k$ or that $p\equiv -1\pmod 3$.

If you understand this, you can figure out the case where $p\equiv 1\pmod 3$ by considering the kernel of the map above.

Comment: You mean $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^*$ at the start of your answer.

Comment: @rogerl Thanks for catching the typo!

Comment: How it shows that all elements of (Z/pZ)* are cubes ?

Comment: It shows it because being a multiple of $3$ in $\mathbb{Z}/(p-1)$ is the same as being a power of $3$ in $(\mathbb{Z}/p)^\ast$ as the groups are isomorphic (although one uses additive notation and the other uses multiplicative notation.)

Comment: @JamesMatthew The first thing is that $(\mathbb{Z}/p)^\ast$ and $\mathbb{Z}/(p-1)$ are isomorphic.  If you're not comfortable with that, then the proof won't make sense.  if you are comfortable, then note that since the multiplication by 3 map is $a\mapsto a+a+a$, when we take that over to multiplicative notation via the isomorphism, it is $a\cdot a\cdot a=a^3$.

Comment: how looks the isomorphism?

Comment: for any $x \in \mathbb{Z}_7^*$  we have that $x^3$ equals $1$ or  $6$ only. So $2,3,4,5$  are  not cubes.

Comment: @Leox But, $7$ is not $-1$ mod 3.

Comment: but the question is to prove it for all $p.$

Comment: Then what can be done in this second part of the question ?

Comment: @Leox The original question is wrong and only applies in the cases where $p\equiv -1\pmod 3$.

Comment: @JamesMatthew only those points in the image of the multiplication by 3 map correspond to cubes when $p\equiv 1\pmod 3$.